# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@theme value=(@style/Theme.ActionBarSize) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-51
>       is also present at [com.github.navasmdc:PhoneTutorial:1.2] AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-40 value=(@style/AppTheme).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-72:19 to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following change in your manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme">
</application>
```

Just add this

> tools:replace="android:theme"

in application tag.

Comment: Thanks @Umair. I have done all these things and get resolved the error